# Set axis ratio to square of line charts in ECharts

Tags: charts, line, axis, echarts

Is there any way on line charts that the ratio of the axes is always the same independent of the width of the axis?

The width of the surrounding container can change and the minimum and maximum of the x-axis should be updated so that the ratio of the axes remains the same.

I have attached two example images.
[image: chart 1]
[image: chart 2]

Comment: Could you explain what the problem? You can define min/max for each axis and result will the same as you picture. Also you can define min/max as function based on data, time and so on.

Comment: `xAxis: { min: (args) => args * 2 }`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I am now calculating the minima and maxima with a function.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you.